# Conditionals with multiple acceptable criteria

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I'm writing a tutorial about plotting data using Shiny for beginners, wherein we might want to alter the parameters of the data to generate reactive plots. Say we have the data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(Num = c(1:10), 
                   Color = rep(c("Yellow", 
                                 "Blue", 
                                 "Orange", 
                                 "Purple", 
                                 "Green"),
                               2))
```

```
>    Num  Color
> 1    1 Yellow
> 2    2   Blue
> 3    3 Orange
> 4    4 Purple
> 5    5  Green
> 6    6 Yellow
> 7    7   Blue
> 8    8 Orange
> 9    9 Purple
> 10  10  Green
```

I want to create a subset of the dataframe that meets certain conditions. Those conditions might vary in both content and length based upon user later input, so they are stored in the variable `num_cond`. If we say `num_cond <- c(2,4,7)`, what I'm struggling to remember is how I can write a conditional statement to identify every row in `test` that contains the numbers within `num_cond`.

I know `subset(test, df$num == num_cond)` would yield an error about mismatched lengths, but I also can't list out conditions because of the variable length (e.g., `subset(test, df$num == num_cond[1] | df$num == num_cond[2])`, etc.)

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==` i.e. `subset(test, Num %in% num_cond)`

Comment: Please note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761.